# Dynamically show / hide a component if its date is not between 2 other dates

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have two inputs: `<input type="date" id="fromDate">` and `<input type="date" id="toDate">`, and then a `*ngFor` loop iterating through a list of items. All of these items have a property `activity_date`.

I want to be able to only show the components having their `activity_date` property between the dates of `fromDate` and `toDate`. For this, I am using MomentJS, more precisely the function `moment(activity_date).isBetween(fromDate, toDate)`.

The problem here is I want to assign the result of the previous method to a `[hidden]` attribute so if an `input` is changed, the `[hidden]` property will be updated.

But here's the catch. How can I do to show / hide the components whenever the `inputs` are changed ?

Here's what I've tried so far:

*view.component.html*

```
<app-events
  type="calendar-item"
  [hidden]="moment(item.activity_date).isBetween(this.fromDate, this.toDate);"
  [data]="item"
  ></app-events>
```

*view.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: "app-view",
  templateUrl: "./view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./view.component.css"]
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  fromDate: string;
  toDate: string;

  item = [
    {
      id: 1,
      activity_date: "14 November 2018",
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}

  isBetweenDate(date: string) {
    return moment(date).isBetween(this.fromDate, this.toDate);
  }
}
```

It works if I write values in the method by hand, and it only works at the loading of the page.

I was trying to look after the `EventEmitter` or the Custom Attributes, but I'm not sure I am moving to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you have done almost right. You made `isBetweenDate` function but don't use it.

I have created an example for you. It is same as your one, **but not exact one**. It compares the date with `fromDate` and `toDate`. So here, you can change dates and you will get an instant output based on the changed dates.

**Here is the link:**

StackBlitz Link: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48bxrq](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48bxrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)